# Deleting an array element declared in struct c++

Tags: c++, arrays, dev-c++

I want to delete the array elements declared under student struct. I have only included parts of the code to reduce confusion.Please find the code below for the two relevant cases:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
struct student
{
char name[20];
int id;

};
struct teacher
{
char name[20];
int id;

};

int main()
{
            case 1:
                cout<<"\t\t\t*********enter record**********"<<endl;
                student st[2];
                for(int count=0; count<2;count++)
                  {
                    cout<<"\t\t\t\tenter student "<<count<<" name"<<endl;
                    cin>>st[count].name;
                    cout<<"\t\t\t\tenter student "<<count<<" id"<<endl;
                    cin>>st[count].id;
                  }
                break; 

            case 5:
                cout<<"\t\t\t*********delete record********"<<endl;
                for(int count=0;count<10;count++)
                {
                    delete st[count].name;
                }    
                break;     

}
```

As seen in case 5 I am trying to delete the elements within the array using delete st[count].name;

I want to delete the elements of name and id in the delete case. However using delete st[count].name gives me a **[Warning] Deleting array** . And when I run the program it gives me a **Program Recieved a signal SIGTRAP, trace/breakpoint trap**. I am a beginner in c++ please help how I can delete the elements stored in these array. Thanks

Comment: You can `delete` only something that has been dynamically allocated by `new`, which is not your case.

Comment: There is nothing to delete there. It’s a char array which has its memory allocated in the struct and cannot be separately freed. Also why use chat arrays and not `std::string`?

Comment: I want to delete the data I am writting into student st[2] in case 1. I want to delete that in case 5

Comment: What do you mean by _"delete the data"_?

Comment: Use [`memset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset).

Comment: @Blacktempel or [`std::fill(std::begin(name), std::end(name), '\0');`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ce85dd52c96ec08c)

Comment: @Hulk That is not a duplicate. They are asking quite different things.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 main problems in your code.

```
cin>>st[count].name
```

You're filling the array with user input, but the array can only hold 20 elements (and the last one must be a null terminator), if user inputs text with more then 19 elements, your program will result in undefined behavior.

Later, you're using

```
delete st[count].name
```

You're using `delete` on an array that is allocated on the stack, which is undefined behavior again, you would only need to use `delete` if you alocate an object using operator `new`, also you should use `delete[]` instead of `delete` for arrays.

The easiest fix to your program is changing `char name[20]` to `std::string`, `std::string` will resize itself to adapt to the text that it's holding dynamicly, while also taking care of clearning memory after itself, so you don't have to worry about that, later on it also has many useful methods that you may find useful, you can read more about `std::string`.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

Comment: can you please recommend me what code I should change to accomplish the task. I want to delete the data I am writting in case 1 in student st[2].

Comment: @UsmanAli can you please say what you mean with "delete the data"? The thing is `delete` has a specific meaning in C++ which is not applicable in your case. You dont need to / cannot `delete` any data (as this answer correctly explains), but maybe you want something else that can be done...

Comment: @user463035818 I am writting data in case 1 using   cin>>st[count].name; and   cin>>st[count].id;         I basically want to delete them in case 5 if possible.

Comment: @UsmanAli if by 'delete the data' you mean 'I want the string to be empty', when using `std::string` you can use `std::string::clear`

Comment: @UsmanAli "I basically want to delete them in case 5 if possible" and what do you mean with "delete them" ? You want if you print the name on the screen that a blank string gets printed?

Comment: @Kaldrr but how do I first of all convert name and id into std::string so that I can later clear them

Comment: @user463035818 yes after delete if I print name or id it returns an empty string

Comment: @UsmanAli then please dont call it delete, because you really dont need to `delete` anything, you just have to assign an empty string